# How are Dorian and Aeolian different?

Tags: theory

In, e.g. the Drunken Sailor, we start the melody on a Dm chord then go down to a Cmajor chord. 
Well, it ends the melody on the D note but...we seem to rest a bit on C as well. It's like C is not the 7th note in the scale.
How is it that the Dorian mode is not just the Aeolian mode with a non-flat sixth?

Answer (score 8):

The drunken sailor is clearly in the dorian mode. And yes, dorian is "just" aeolian with a natural sixth. But this is true for any mode apart from locrian, that it is just either major (ionian) or natural minor (aeolian) with just one note changed:

```
mixolydian = ionian  b7
lydian     = ionian  #4
phrygian   = aeolian b2
dorian     = aeolian ♮6
```

You can always move from one mode to the next by just changing one note. If you start from locrian, you get the following sequence of modes:

```
      b5->5       b2->2      b6->6     b3->3         b7->7      4->#4
locrian -> phrygian -> aeolian -> dorian -> mixolydian -> ionian -> lydian
```

by each time moving the appropriate note up by one semi-tone. Of course, you can also move in the opposite direction (from lydian to locrian) by adding the appropriate flats to the modes.

Playing that sequence is a nice exercise for studying modes and for seeing and hearing their relationships.

Answer (score 1):

It can't merely be said that a tune is necessarily in a particular key or mode. Minor melodies can (and do) use notes from all the minor scales - harmonic, melodic and natural. There's no 'rule' saying a tune must stick to one scale set of notes.

Yes, Aeolian and Dorian differ by just that one note you mentioned. If that particular note doesn't appear in a tune, then it's difficult to say which mode something is in. At that point, we look for a rest point, or home. That then establishes which mode, on which key note, from which parent key, the piece is in.

In D Dorian, the 7th note *is* C, but rather like the natural minor it's not a proper *leading note*, in that it isn't one semitone below the root. It just doesn't sound like it *has* to be moved on to that root. That's one of the vagaries of some minors, and some modes.

Answer (score 1):

1. Harmonic minor scale  = Aeolian ♮7
2. Melodic minor scale  = Aeolian ♮7 and ♮6
3. Dorian = Aeolian ♮6

I like to call Dorian substitution for the Aeolian "the Melodic Minus scale"
It is sort of the Melodic minor scale minus the Harmonic element. It returns
the ♮7 to its natural minor state, leaving only the ♮6 as an accidental.

Of course this holds for every mode substitution with an equivalent interval:  Phrygian on Locrian, Lydian on Ionian, Mixolydian on Dorian etc.